# Google VM instance website permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I want to build a website on a Google Cloud VM instance. I have set up the DNS and created an SSH key to connect to Filezilla so far. Now I want to upload an index.html "Hello World" file.

[image]

But I keep getting a permission error. I cannot delete or edit anything. But the permissions are set like this:

[image]

I am trying to upload an index.html file as the front page of my website. Am I in the wrong folder? How can I gain permission to edit the folder if it's the right one?

Comment: Are you the owner of that file? if not , try to add the group that your in a write permission and you are done.

Comment: I cannot even change the write permission using my google terminal. I get a operation no permitted error. I can access the files via my Mac terminal with an SSH key and then via the google cloud browser terminal. Both don't let me change or add anything.

Comment: Can you run commands as super user in this machine? (sudo su <command>)?

Comment: Yes sudo works. My problem is, I need to use an SSH key user on FileZilla. How do I give the user sudo access? FileZilla doesn't run sudo commands.

Comment: Do you have to use FileZilla? can you access the VM directly with an ssh from your mac?

Comment: Yes, I found the answer. You need to do a "sudo chown your_username directory" and I can let my username own the directory. It works

Comment: Make sense - happy you succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let your user own the directory. Once you create a SSH key user, go to your Google Cloud terminal located on the SSH button beside your VM instance. Then add the code below. This way you do not need to change any permissions for the file.

```
sudo chown USERNAME DIRECTORY
```

The directory in this case is the one with the website files `/var/www/html`

Now when you log into FileZilla with an SSH key user, you can edit the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```